# How to properly lock List<String> getter in C#

Tags: c#, list, locking

I am wondering how to properly lock the getter of type `List<String>`. I have one static class that looks something like this:

```
class FirstClass {
static private locker = new object();   
static private List<String> _my_list;

public static List<String> my_list {
    get {
        lock(locker) {
            return my_list;
        }
    }
}

private static void thread_func() {
    // do something periodicaly with the list
    // for example:

    lock(locker){
        _my_list.Add();
        _my_list.RemoveAt();
        ...
    }
}
```

}

Then, I have another class that looks like this:

```
class SecondClass {
private void thread_func() {
    foreach(string s in FirstClass.my_list) {
        // read every item in the list
    }
}
```

}

So, first class has a public list that the second class uses. First class periodically updates the list in one thread, and second class reads the list at an random interval on a second thread.

Does this locking mechanism ensure that the list will not be modified by the first class while the second class is reading it and vice-versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

All that ensures is that the list isn't modified as you return it from the property.
Since field access is already guaranteed to be atomic, it's an utterly useless lock.

You need to put a lock around the entire `foreach` loop.

---

Note that you can achieve better performance by using a ReaderWriterLockSlim, and even better performance by using a `ConcurrentBag<T>` without any locks.

Comment: A couple of caveats: *(1)* `ReaderWriterLockSlim` isn't a panacea. Depending on access patterns etc it can often have poorer performance than a plain `lock`. *(2)* `List<T>` has an explicit ordering, `ConcurrentBag<T>` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of getting into locking your lists you could expose them as ReadOnlyCollections and also provide a method for adding to the lists that handles the logic.

Comment: Exposing it as a ReadOnlyCollection won't prevent the underlying list from changing by other means while it's being read by hapless callers.  You'd have to use copy-on-write logic which gets expensive.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. In particular the first lock shown only protects for the duration of ***obtaining the list reference***. After that, other threads can compete while the caller does... well, whatever they do after accessing `my_list`.

Answer (score 1):

You would be safe with a Copy:

```
public static List<String> my_list 
{
    get {
        lock(locker) {
            return my_list.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

It depends on your req's if that's acceptable.

Comment: @Slaks: I have no idea how big the list will be. And it's relative to the amount of work in the foreach, another unknown.

Comment: @Slaks: Knuth might have word to say about favouring faster over safer. How does it go again?

Comment: By design this list won't be bigger than 5000 elements, so copying it might be applicable.

Comment: @coldcrow, copying up to 5000 string references is not a lot in absolute terms. Do realize you would be iterating a snapshot.

Comment: @Henk Holterman Yes, I am aware of the snapshot. I've carefully thought about it and in my situation I don't find any problem with iterating a snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

No, your reader is only locking the list for the duration of the property access. You need to lock the list around the entire foreach loop if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, the locking that you have is completely useless. It will only protect the access to the variable that contains the list, but once you have got a copy of that reference, the access to the list is completely unprotected.

You shouldn't have a property that returns a reference to the list, you should have methods that does what you need with the list:

```
class FirstClass {

  static private locker = new object();   
  static private List<String> _my_list;

  public static void Add(string item) {
    lock(locker) {
      my_list.Add(item);
    }
  }

  public static void RemoveAt(int index) {
    lock(locker) {
      my_list.RenoveAt(index);
    }
  }

  public static IEnumerable<string> GetEnumerable() {
    lock(locker) {
      List<string> copy = new List<string>(my_list);
      return copy;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't call `GetEnumerator`; this won't compile.  Also, copying is  slow.

Comment: @SLaks: You are right, I changed it to just return the copy of the list. Regarding the speed, it depends. It can slow down the application a lot more to lock the list while looping.